# installing pip for python2.7

Tags: installation, python, pip, version

When I originally installed pip and numpy it was through python 37. I need to know how I can switch the installation to python 27 or if I need to uninstall it and reinstall it in a different file location accessible to python 2 and 3. Copy of cmd script is below:

C:\Users\jarob>pip -V
pip 19.0.3 from c:\users\jarob\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

C:\Users\jarob>pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from c:\users\jarob\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

C:\Users\jarob>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\jarob\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.16.4)
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 1):

Use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). They allow you to use isolated python instances with different set of packages. Python 3 comes with `venv` module that lets you create one using

```
python -m venv venv
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

When you do this your prompt changes from `d:\my_project>` to `(venv) d:\my_project>`, so you know you're inside a virtual environment and every package you install will be isolated to that environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a Python distribution manager. This will allow you to run multiple versions of python in isolated environments. I have environments for python 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7 that each have their own dependencies.
My manger of choice is [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) but there are a few others available.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how I can switch the installation to Python 2.7.

On Windows, you can manually install the latest version of Python 2.7 (which is currently [Python 2.7.16](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716/)) from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/). You likely *won't* want to add 2.7 to your System Path during installation unless you want `python` (2.7) to replace `python` (3.7) at the command line. Other than that, there should be no issues with running 2.7 and 3.7 side-by-side.

> When I originally installed `pip` and `numpy`, it was through Python 3.7.

`pip` should come with the Windows Python 2.7 installer (above), but you can always use [pip-get.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). Similarly, `numpy` can be re-installed in Python 2.7 as in 3.7.

One thing to remember is that Python installations are entirely separate on Windows, regardless of whether you install Python 2.7 and Python 3.7 "normally", or clone them with virtual environments (as detailed in the other answers to this question). You will *always* need to re-install packages for a new installation. There are no "common" folders for e.g. `pip` and `numpy` (or any other modules) between Python installations of any kind.

Lastly, make sure that you are calling the correct version of `python` (as alluded to above). If you `python -m pip install numpy` where `python` refers to e.g. `C:\path\to\Python27\python.exe`, `python` (refering to `C:\path\to\Python37\python.exe`) won't be able to use it (primarily due to being separate installations but also differences between 2.7 and 3.7).

If you want to have Python 2.7 and 3.7 available at the command line, you can rename one (or both) `python.exe` interpreters e.g.:

- `C:\path\to\Python27\python.exe` → `C:\path\to\Python27\python2.exe`
- `C:\path\to\Python37\python.exe` → `C:\path\to\Python37\python3.exe`

This assumes both their base folders are in your System Path. You can also specify their full paths when calling them.